# Python: Need to download images from URL in a loop (JPG and PNG)

Tags: python, image, download, png, jpeg

my school has digital books, but to access those I need to go through several logins and that way it takes a long time to get to my school book. On top of that I need an internet connection to see them.

I have however found out that the books are on the publishers server as separate images (both jpg's and png's), now I'd like to download those images and combine them into a PDF file.

The problem I'm running into is that the files are not generally accessible so I need to give the script the exact URL, and I can't get it to go to the next file.

This is what I've got so far: [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/Jd2eaH65)

```
import os
import urllib
import requests
import sys
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.lib import utils
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shutil
import nltk  
from urllib import urlopen

#Change those variables:

URL = "http://cdpcontent.toegang.nu/c436b908-7a8d-49ce-ae5e-24892fa06fd7/20140808123622/extract/assets/img/layout/page-00"

#_____________________________________________________

FILE_END_JPG = ".jpg"
FILE_END_PNG = ".png"
SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY = "images"

NUM = 1 # Default 1
MAX_NUM = 500

builded_link_jpg = URL + str(NUM) + FILE_END_JPG
builded_link_png = URL + str(NUM) + FILE_END_PNG

def link_alive(some_url):
        try:
                html = urlopen(some_url).read()
                four_zero_four = "De door u gevraagde pagina of resource kan helaas niet worden gevonden."
                if four_zero_four in html:
                        #print "Link dead."
                        return 0
                else:
                        #print "Link alive."
                        return 1

        except Exception as Error:
                print Error
                print "\nError in check_dead_link function.\n"


def save(NUM, MAX_NUM, SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY, FILE_END_PNG, FILE_END_JPG, URL):
        save_name = 0

        try:
                if not os.path.exists(SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY):
                        os.makedirs(SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY)
                        print SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY + " created."

                print "All images will be saved to the folder:", SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY + "\n"

                while NUM <= MAX_NUM:

                                        if link_alive(builded_link_jpg) == 1:
                                                print "This is a JPG page\n"
                                                save_name = "%04d" % save_name
                                                image = str(save_name) + FILE_END_JPG
                                                save_name = int(save_name)
                                                save_name += 1
                                                urllib.urlretrieve(builded_link_jpg, SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY + "//" + image)
                                                NUM += 1
                                                print builded_link_jpg + " saved.\n"

                                        else:
                                                print "This is a PNG page\n"
                                                save_name = "%04d"% save_name
                                                image = str(save_name) + FILE_END_PNG
                                                save_name = int(save_name)
                                                save_name += 1
                                                urllib.urlretrieve(builded_link_jpg, SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY + "//" + image)
                                                NUM += 1
                                                print builded_link_jpg + " saved.\n"

                print "Done saving all the images!"


        except Exception as Error:
                print Error
                print "\nFail in save function.\n"

save(NUM, MAX_NUM, SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY, FILE_END_PNG, FILE_END_JPG, URL)
```

The part where I'm stuck is the last while, it keeps downloading the same picture but with a incremented name ;/

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: You need to reconstruct builded_link_jpg and builded_link_png inside the while() loop, after incrementing NUM.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to update the value of `builded_link_jpg` inside the loop!